# Using cypress.io to test SSL HTTPS certificate

Tags: cypress

(NOTE: I cross-posted to the cypress forum, but wasn't sure how active it was, so thought better of it, and realized I should have used StackOverlow in the first place)

New to cypress, very much liking it !   I've worked through the tutorials, and also searched in the docs.  I'm wondering if I can use cypress to inspect/assert against my https certificate.   I'm new to enabling a secure certificate, and am currently using LetsEncrypt as my CA.   I'm looking to navigate to different versions of my url (e.g. https://domain.tld, https://www.domain.tld, http://domain.tld).  I'd like to use cypress to verify that I'm getting a secure terminated connection when I expect, perhaps inspecting the cert for a the commonname ?

Answer (score 1):

Cypress is a JavaScript framework and tests are written in JavaScript.

So you could use an npm package to get the SSL certificate for you and then you can perform any assertion you want in the object that represents your certificate.

I suggest you the `get-ssl-certificate` npm package. More info about and how to use it [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/get-ssl-certificate).