# View certificate of webpages using cypress

Tags: cypress

Is there a way in cypress to view the page certificate information?
manually, we can simply click the lock icon next to the URL in the top panel and then click on 'certificate'.
I wish to run an assertion on the 'Issued by' section. If the certificate is issued by a specific party then my test should pass, else it should fail.
If there's a way to do this please guide me.
Thanks[image]
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using cypress.io to test SSL HTTPS certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60022371/using-cypress-io-to-test-ssl-https-certificate)

Comment: @DiogoRocha i went through this link and then the npm package; by looking at the documentation given on the package's page it appears that this should be a solution to my query. However, when i run the code that is given with the package, I get this error in the console
`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'getPeerCertificate' of undefined
  `
any idea on how do I remove this?

Answer (score 3):

Using the https://github.com/johncrisostomo/get-ssl-certificate package as @DiogoRocha suggested looks the simplest, but his linked answer doesn't have Cypress implementation details.

`get-ssl-certificate` uses Node `https`, so you need a task to invoke it.

**cypress.config.js**

```js
module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents (on) {
      on('task', {
        getCertificate: (host) => {
          const sslCertificate = require('get-ssl-certificate')
          return sslCertificate.get(host)
        }
      })
    },
  },
})
```

**Test**

```js
cy.task('getCertificate', 'stackoverflow.com')      // pass only host part of URL
  .its('valid_to')
  .should('eq', 'Jun 11 20:46:25 2024 GMT')
```

[image]

---

For reference, the full certificate object returned is as follows (long data truncated here with "...")

```js
{
    "subject": {
        "CN": "stackoverflow.com"
    },
    "issuer": {
        "C": "US",
        "O": "Let's Encrypt",
        "CN": "E1"
    },
    "subjectaltname": "DNS:*.stackoverflow.com, DNS:stackoverflow.com",
    "infoAccess": {
        "OCSP - URI": [
            "http://e1.o.lencr.org"
        ],
        "CA Issuers - URI": [
            "http://e1.i.lencr.org/"
        ]
    },
    "ca": false,
    "bits": 256,
    "pubkey": {
        "type": "Buffer",
        "data": [...]
    },
    "asn1Curve": "prime256v1",
    "nistCurve": "P-256",
    "valid_from": "Mar 13 20:46:26 2024 GMT",
    "valid_to": "Jun 11 20:46:25 2024 GMT",
    "fingerprint": "...",
    "fingerprint256": "...",
    "fingerprint512": "...",
    "ext_key_usage": [...],
    "serialNumber": "...",
    "raw": {
        "type": "Buffer",
        "data": [...]
    },
    "pemEncoded": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- ... -----END CERTIFICATE-----"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After several tries to get information about the server certificate from JS build in methods like TLSSocket or libraries like puppeteer or the one mentioned above to grab that information I came to the current solution. It's not really a proper solution for me, but it works. After more than 3 years, it's still a problem to get the certification information.

I use `cy.exec()` to execute curl from the system which outputs the information I need to grab the expiry date of the certificate. Here I use an extra command to call it.

Requirements:

- curl is installed on the system

my commands.js

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('checkCertificate', (url, daysBeforeWarning = 14) => {
  const command = `curl ${url} -vI --stderr - | grep "expire date" | cut -d":" -f 2-`
  cy.exec(command).then((result) => {
    const expiryDate = result.stdout.trim()
    const expiryTime = new Date(expiryDate).getTime()
    const now = new Date().getTime()
    const warningDate = now + (daysBeforeWarning * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)

    cy.log(`Certificate expires on ${expiryDate}`)

    expect(warningDate).to.be.lessThan(expiryTime, `certificate do not expires in less than ${daysBeforeWarning} days`)
  })
})
```

and in your spec file you can call it:

```js
it('check certificate', () => {
  cy.checkCertificate('https://stackoverflow.com')
})
```

It executes an extra https request against the url and grab the information. It's kind of slow, but it works for me. Still feels like a workaround.

so you can check, what information you need (ex. issuer) and grep it from the stdout of your curl request.

Hopefully, Cypress will include this kind of information somehow in the future.

HTH.